# Is it better to write 2 nearly identical functions, or to determine the logic based on the input variables

Tags: c#

For simplicity, lets assume I have to write 2 functions :

```
int f1(int number, int var1) {
    return number/var1;
}
```

and

```
int f2(int number, int var2) {
    return number-var2;
}
```

Could I combine the two like this:

```
int f3(int number, int var1, int var2) {
    return number/var1 - var2;
```

and call the

```
function f3(num, 1, var)
```

to achieve f2's functionality and like this:

```
function f3(num, var, 0)
```

to achieve f1's functionality.

Lets assume the code is slightly longer and duplicating the function is something I prefer not to do, but the change in functionality is as simple as I wrote above.

EDIT: slightly, as in about 10 lines of code.

Thanks

Comment: `f3` seems confusing. I'd stick with the two functions for clarity. And calrity should be your most important metric [*Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler)

Comment: IMO It's impossible to answer this question effectively because the answer will depend on the *actual* code, not some hypothetical and unrealistic example... And answers are likely to be subjective.

Comment: That said  this is entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context.
You can also try this:

```
int f3(int number, int var1 = 1, int var2 = 0) =>
    number/var1 - var2;
```

and call it:

```
f3(number, var1: 10);
f3(number, var2: 10);
f3(number, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 6):

I would continue to make `f1` and `f2` the *public* interface to your functionality and make `f3` a private implementation detail:

```
public int f1(int number, int var1) {
    return f3(num, var, 0);
}

public int f2(int number, int var2) {
    return f3(num, 1, var) ;
}

private int f3(int number, int var1, int var2) {
    return number/var1 - var2;
}
```

This maximizes reuse whilst not littering calling code with what seems, fundamentally, an implementation detail (that the implementations are *currently* practically identical).

Comment: This makes it clear to the consumer of the class but it still seems a bit convoluted for anyone debugging/examining the code. If the line was more complicated (which might be the idea) then yes, but for a simple math expression..?

Comment: @Liam - what I'm thinking of is e.g. a swiss army comparison method that is then used to implement all of the equality ops for a class. That's a not uncommon place where I find myself writing such code. They've indicated that the real code is longer.

Comment: True, I guess [context is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698240/is-it-better-to-write-2-nearly-identical-functions-or-to-determine-the-logic-ba#comment92323121_52698240). At the same time all this feels like we're dancing on the head of a pin! :) Anyhoo.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: If the functions do different things - which they appear to do based on your examples - they should be separate functions. And, you should give them names that help indicate the function being performed.